# Small JSP app does not work

Tags: java, php, mysql, tomcat, netbeans

I wrote a small JSP app, just to test the connection. I use XAMPP. Module Apche, mySql, Tomcat are running. I use Netbeans 7.4. The code is :

```
 <%@page language="java" contentType="text/html"%>
 <%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
  <html><head><title>JDBC test</title></head><body>
    <%
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8084/book_shop_db", "root", "");
        System.out.println("CONN = " + conn);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from books");
    %><table border= "1"><%
        ResultSetMetaData resMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
        int nCols = resMetaData.getColumnCount();
        %><tr><%
        for (int kCol = 1; kCol <= nCols; kCol++) {
            out.print("<td><b>" + resMetaData.getColumnName(kCol) + "</b></td>");
        }
            %></tr><%
        while (rs.next()) {
            %><tr><%
        for (int kCol = 1; kCol <= nCols; kCol++) {
            out.print("<td>" + rs.getString(kCol) + "</td>");
        }
            %></tr><%
        }
            %></table><%
        conn.close();
        %>
  </body></html>
```

When I run the app, the following error appear :

```
 HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 11
```

where line 11 is :

```
  11:             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

In Netbeans, in Tools->Servers->Tomcat I have :
      username: ide
      password : *******

Ok. Password can be shown no roblem.

Server port is : 8084. In XAMPP, ports are : 
for Apache : 100, 443 (Ok)
for mySql: 3306
for Tomcat: 8005, 8809, 8080.

I really am confused. How can I make the app run ?

Thank you.

EB

Comment: Make sure that you added JDBC driver in you class path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the mysql jdbc driver from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) and put it in your WEB-INF/lib directory.

Comment: I downloaded it and put it in the directory. It works now. Thanx. Another question: I don't want to make these operationsevery time. Where can I put the mysql jdbc jar to access it automatically ?

Comment: Its the common way to put your dependencies in the lib folder (per app), because different types of apps (having dependencies of the same type but a different version) might run on the same server. Another way is to put them in your servers lib folder, but that might cause side effects, which may be hard to resolve.